# Python Regex 4 letter word with min 1 capital letter

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a regex-solution for finding all words with max 4. letters and at least 1 capital letter:

Examples of positive matches:

```
A, Ab, AbC, ABC, Abcd, bACD, aBCd, abcD
```

Examples of negative matches:

```
abcd
```

Do you know if this is possible with regex?

I started off with something like this:

```
match = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]{1,4}", string)
```

but how do I eliminate the case of only small letters?

EDIT: I would like to find these patterns within a string of words such as this:

"in this sentence, we want to find Abcd and Hi but not abcd and not abcdefgHI"

Result: ["Abcd", "Hi"]

Comment: Not in a reasonable size.  It's easy enough to filter: `match = [s for s in re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]{1,4}",string) if s != s.lower()]`

Comment: Right, that's what I thought... Thank you for confirming my suspicion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a lookahead to check if atleast one capital exists in the string, then use your existing `regex` to match any letters ranging from 1-4 in length.

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z]{1,4})$
```

Output:

```
import re
test = ['A', 'Ab', 'AbC', 'ABC', 'Abcd', 'bACD', 'aBCd', 'abcD', 'abcd', 'a', 'abcdgehfyF', 'ABccdhdhdhd']
pattern = r'^(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z]{1,4})$'

for i in test:
    print(i, re.match(pattern, i))

A <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='A'>
Ab <re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='Ab'>
AbC <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='AbC'>
ABC <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='ABC'>
Abcd <re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='Abcd'>
bACD <re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='bACD'>
aBCd <re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='aBCd'>
abcD <re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abcD'>
abcd None
a None
abcdgehfyF None
ABccdhdhdhd None
```

To match this in a sentence, we can use this pattern

```
(?<=\s)(?=[^ ]*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z]{1,4})(?=\s)


string = "in this sentence, we want to find Abcd and Hi but not abcd and not abcdefgHI"
re.findall(r'(?<=\s)(?=[^ ]*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z]{1,4})(?=\s)', string)
#['Abcd', 'Hi']
```

Comment: This seems close but it doesn't seem to enforce the requirement on `max 4. letters`. For example: `re.match(pattern, 'aABCD')`. Maybe the question is not clear on this, and that max indicates the max of the population.

Comment: @MarkM I edited the question to include `$` to only match strings which are maximum length of 4. Could you forsee any further issues with this?

Comment: @PacketLoss Thank you very much, this works great! I haven't quite figured out how to do lookahead yet. So thank you for the hint!! However, I should have been more precise in my question, because I am looking to find this pattern as part of a longer pattern and the string can contain many other words as well and I am not keen on checking each word separately. So I assume the $ and ^ are for checking the beginning/end of the string? Can I change that to the beginning and end of a word? Something like \b?

Comment: I updated the question and put an example sentence and the result I would need.

Comment: @Tobi I have added a pattern for the sentence

Comment: Great thank you so much PacketLoss, I still have a lot to learn about regex. The look-ahead seems very useful but I am not 100% sure what it does. Will do some more learning on these, thanks again for the hint and proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try a simple way that does not involve lookarounds, as it may be instructive.

1. Consider a regex for matching 1-4 characters where the first MUST be capitalized
2. Consider a regex for matching 2-4 characters where the second MUST be capitalized
3. And so on...
4. Combine the four cases using operator `|`

**Tip:** use `\b` at the start and end to match only full words.

Alternatively, you could use lookarounds to create a more concise regex. For example, using negative lookahead `(?!...)` as follows:

```
\b(?![a-z]+\b)[A-Za-z]{1,4}\b
```

**Demonstration:** https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cb(%3F!%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5Cb)%5BA-Za-z%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%5Cb&test_string=in%20this%20sentence%2C%20we%20want%20to%20find%20Abcd%20and%20Hi%20but%20not%20abcd%20and%20not%20abcdefgH

Comment: Thank you for the input Patrick this was something I thought of as well, but as I am new to regex, I thought there might be a more elegant solution. I thought maybe there is a way to do a negative match of some sort "match any {1,4} letter word that is NOT only [a-z]{1,4}"

Comment: Yes, that can be done via negative lookahead e.g. `\b(?![a-z]+\b)[A-Za-z]{1,4}\b`

Answer (score 1):

You can assert whitespace boundaries to the left and right, and assert at least a single uppercase char `[A-Z]`.

Then you can match 1-4 times `[a-zA-Z]`.

```
(?<!\S)(?=[a-zA-Z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]{1,4}(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tsr06G/1)

Example

```
import re

regex = r"(?<!\S)(?=[a-zA-Z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z]{1,4}(?!\S)"
s = "Abcd and Hi but not abcd and not abcdefgHI $aBc"
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['Abcd', 'Hi']
```